# Trying to remove the second colon : and everything after it in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I'm using spotfire version 11.4.3. I'm trying to remove the second colon : and everything after it.
For example

`Hello:W:Boy` I need the output `Hello:W`

`Motorcycle:B:racing` I need the output `Motorcycle:B`

Thank you for the help!

I've tried using the RXREPLACE function but I cant figure out how to get the characters to the right of the second colon :.

Comment: Combining the functions `Left` and `Find` should work (when I look at the functions available here: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_text_functions.htm )

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
Left(inputstring,Find(':', inputstring,2)-1)
```

This should return the left part of the string with a length of the position of the second ':' minus 1.

Comment: For some reason the find function is not identifying the ':' in the string, it's returning 0.

Comment: Oops, I have the parameters to `Find` in the wrong order, I will do an edit ....